# how to pass a converter (constraints not applicable for generic arguments)

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I want to pass a converter to a method, and the constraint must be that the converter always gets a string as argument. I tried the following, but it won't compile:

```
class Test
{
   public void Foo(string val, Converter<Tin,Tout> conv)
        where Tin:string
   {
      myObj = conv(val);
   }
}
```

Comment: @codemanix - I think you're over-complicating by adding a generic type constraint for Tin when it's always going to be a string. See my answer and it'll do exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a function signature should carry a generic argument, or an argument with a generic type parameter, that type parameter must be part of the method declaration and the method becomes generic itself.

Especially, the generic type arguments you want to constrain must be part of the method signature of Foo.

Try it this way:

```
class Test 
{ 
   public void Foo<Tout>(string val, Converter<string, Tout> conv) 
   { 
      myObj = conv(val); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: That wont compile. String cannot be used as a constraint.

Comment: It now tells me that string would be not valid constraint and that only interfaces or non-sealed classes are applicable.

Comment: Ok, I forgot about the non-sealed constraint. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

What's the point of constraining Tin if it's always going to be a string?

```
class Test 
{ 
   public void Foo<Tout>(string val, Converter<string,Tout> conv) 
   { 
      myObj = conv(val); 
   } 
}
```

Just get rid of the `Tin` type and use `string` in your `Converter`. I think you're over-complicating things.

You cannot use string as a `generic constraint` as it's a `sealed class`. This makes perfect sense as nothing can inherit from `string` so why add a constraint for `string`?

I.e. If you **COULD** inherit from string:

```
public SuperString : string
```

Then you could use `string` as a constraint and pass through `SuperString` as `Tin`. However you **CANNOT** do this as `string` is a `sealed class`. Therefor the only object you could pass to `Tin` is `String` anyway.

Because of this, you may as well get rid of `Tin` and use the code I wrote above.

Answer (score 1):

Your code nonsensical.

`where Tin:string` is not valid. Fix that, and add the generic parameters to your method.

Comment: What is nonsensical about that? Beside the fact that it doesn't compile, but this is part of the question. I want to constrain the converter in a way so that it always takes string but may return anything.

Comment: @codemanix - why do you need to constrain it to string when the Converter can just take string as the first parameter?

Comment: @codemanix: If can only be `string`, why not just use `string`. It cant be anything else.... There is no need for a generic parameter for `Tin` in the first place. See @GenericTypeTea 's answer above.